# How to set Last-Modified response header in Spring JSPs

Tags: spring, jsp

I am using the following configuration for setting cache related response headers in Spring.

```
<mvc:interceptors>
    <mvc:interceptor>
        <mvc:mapping path="/*.*"/>
        <bean id="webContentInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.WebContentInterceptor">
            <property name="cacheSeconds" value="31536000"/>
            <property name="useExpiresHeader" value="true"/>
            <property name="useCacheControlHeader" value="true"/>
        </bean>
    </mvc:interceptor>
    <!-- Map other interceptors here -->
</mvc:interceptors>
```

**Question: How do I set Last-Modified here ?** 
[Another Q : Is it just me or its really difficult to find such documentation, especially on property names from Spring docs ?]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to me there is a better way to achieve this in Spring Framework.

There is a filter called **ShallowEtagHeaderFilter**. You just need to specify this as a filter in your web.xml.

Please read its javadoc [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/filter/ShallowEtagHeaderFilter.html) for more details.

Hope this helps you. Cheers.